# How do I print an ASP clientID in a web page?

Tags: asp.net

How do I print an ASP clientID in a web page?

```
  <td class="ColDatos" colspan="1"><asp:TextBox ID="FECHA_APLICACION" runat="server" Width="85%"></asp:TextBox>


                                        <a href="javascript:alert('<%=FECHA_APLICACION.clientID %>')">
                        mostrar fecha
                                        </a></td>
```

update: i need do print in the asp side, no code behind side(onload,oninit,etc)( I'm not familiar with asp terms)

Comment: too generic question, please explain better what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client side only:

```
<a href='javascript:alert("<%= FECHA_APLICACION.ClientID %>")'>
```

how does this work?

i believe if it does not work yet is only about the single/double quote escapes...

Answer (score 2):

in Page_PreRender you can do:

```
myLink.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript:alert('" + FECHA_APLICACION.ClientID + "')");
```

this would work if you have mylink declared as a server control link and not simply an "< a>" in your page.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 <a href="javascript:alert('<%=FECHA_APLICACION.ClientID %>')">mostrar fecha</a>
```

instead of (note: upper case 'C' in ClientID)

```
<a href="javascript:alert('<%=FECHA_APLICACION.clientID %>')">mostrar fecha </a>
```

Comment: is so, my problem was that.. the 'C' in lowercase