# JavaScript Validation in Content Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

This is Part of the code that I used for validating Registration form in contenet page. The validation part is not working. Any help appreciated

Master Page

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs"      Inherits="testjavascript.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>    
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    HI
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

Contenet Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="testjavascript.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validations() {
    //-----------First name----------
    if (document.getElementById("txtFName").value == "")
    alert("plz enter first name");
     return false;
    }
  </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFnameValidate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return Validations();" runat="server"></asp:Button>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Try looking at the source of your document.  I bet the ID for the textbox isn't what you are expecting.

Comment: OnClientClick="return Validations(); Change this to
Onclick="Validations();"

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
document.getElementById("<%=txtFName.ClientID=>").value == ""
```

See [How do I print an ASP clientID in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036031/how-do-i-print-an-asp-clientid-in-a-web-page).

Comment: @jessica Could you be more specific ?

Comment: I tried adding clientID and it doesnt work. Is there any problem with the placement of script tags?

Comment: What I meant by "specific" was : What is not working ? Did you got an error ? What is the resulted HTML ?

Comment: The page gets loaded and when i dont enter anything in the name textbox and click the button the alert box is not displayed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45151/discussion-between-cubitouch-and-jessica)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should an aspx validator to make your code easier. Take a look on this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtFName" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="*" runat="server"/> 

<asp:TextBox ID="txtFnameValidate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="txtFnameValidate" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="*" runat="server"/>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="if(!Page_ClientValidate) return; DoSomething();" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

Page_ClientValidate function is builtin in aspx (web forms) and returns false is one of the validators is not valid. Of course, example above is a simple one, but you can create more complicated scenarios.

Comment: Thanks! im aware of these but my company wants to use javascript for validations

Comment: No idea about this, you can create some function to get the control where id contains a substring of use JQuery. For example:

   $('input[id*="myid"]').val()

This will get the input element where id contains myid. ASP.NET generates long id on client side, but you can controls from server side what substring should be included.

Comment: By the way, if you do not want to use JQuery, you can check my article on this link: http://anvlpopescu.wordpress.com/2014/01/16/getting-controls-values-from-a-custom-list-form/

I have created code for SharePoint, but it can be applied on normal ASP.NET pages as well.